# How to automatically load a certain webpage content with Ajax and jQuery when page is first loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

When opening my webpage none of the Ajax content loads until one of the links is clicked then displaying the content connected to that link.

This is where the content is loaded into the main webpage at ext-content:

```html
<main>
    <article class="ext-content">

    </article>
    </main>
```

This is the javascript which loads the content when one of the links is clicked:

```js
$('section li').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'includes/ext-content/'+$(this).data('content')+'.html',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response) {
        $('.ext-content').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
```

These are the links which then load the content into ext-content when clicked:

```html
<section id="section-links">
      <p>Kies een van de onderstaande opties:</p>
      <ul id="componenten-links">
        <li data-content="cpu-shop">CPU's</li>
        <li data-content="moederbord-shop">Moederborden</li>
        <li data-content="geheugen-shop">Geheugen</a></li>
        <li data-content="hardschijf-shop">Harde schijven</a></li>
        <li data-content="grafischekaart-shop">Grafische kaarten</a></li>
        <li data-content="voeding-shop">Voedingen</a></li>
        <li data-content="behuizing-shop">Behuizingen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

The code below will automatically load a specific webpage when the page loads, but this only works if I manually type in the webpage.html. Is there a way to make this code below work where it automatically takes one of the links listed above instead of me having to type in a specific webpage.html? Otherwise I would need a different script for each webpage.

```js
 $('section li').ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'includes/ext-content/cpu-shop.html',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response) {
        $('.ext-content2').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why not use `.load()`? https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$(function(){
  $('.ext-content').load('includes/ext-content/' + $('section li').eq(0).data('content') + '.html');
  
  $('section li').click(function() {
    $('.ext-content').load('includes/ext-content/' + $(this).data('content') + '.html');
  });
});
```

See More: https://api.jquery.com/load/

> When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

when the page is ready, this will load the first `LI` and collect it's `data` attribute.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('section li').load(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'includes/ext-content/cpu-shop.html',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response) {
        $('.ext-content2').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
```

Use the load method instead of ready.

Comment: Yes but the question was how to load the content without having to have a specific html page in the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `document.ready` for load data on page load.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'includes/ext-content/cpu-shop.html',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response) {
        $('.ext-content2').html(response);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes but the question was how to load the content without having to have a specific html page in the javascript code.